# Why do we evaluate $-x^{z-1}e^{-x}$ as zero when explaining the gamma function through integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function, visualization

The gamma function is the integral of $x^{z-1}e^{-x}$

If you integrate by parts you get two terms.

The first one is $-x^{z-1}e^{-x}$ and this is bound by infinity and zero.

If you plug in infinity, it is equal to zero, and when you plug in zero, it is equal to zero, and $0-0$ is zero, so we can remove it.

But if you plot the graph, or integrate it, you can see the area between the curve and the $x$ axis is not zero.

Are you supposed to be visualising the "$f(x)g(x)$" part of integration by parts $(f(x)g'(x) = f(x)g(x) - f'(x)g(x))$ as an area or not ?

Is there a geometric explanation of this ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that in integration by parts, you write $\int u dv = uv - \int v du$, the "uv" term is not being integrated. If the evaluation of $uv$ at the endpoints gives zero, that just means that $\int d(uv)=0$.

Comment: Am i right in thinking that "uv" is not being integrated because it is the result of an integration ? You simply need to insert the right values for the boundaries, and calculate what the area under the curve is ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the integration by parts rule as
$$\int \limits_a^b [f(x) g'(x) + f'(x) g(x)] \, \mathrm{d} x = \left[f(x) g(x)\right]_{x=a}^{x=b}$$
to see that the term on the right-hand side can indeed be understood as an area (a signed area, to be precise). However, it is not the area under the graph of $f g'$ ! Instead, as can be seen from the equation, it is the area between the graph of $f g' + f' g = (fg)'$ and the $x$-axis .

For the gamma function integral we have $f(x) = x^{z-1}$ and $g(x) = - \mathrm{e}^{-x}$ . Since the term on the right-hand side vanishes in this case, we conclude that the signed area beneath the graph of the function $$x \mapsto x^{z-1} \mathrm{e}^{-x} - (z-1) x^{z-2} \mathrm{e}^{-x} = [x - (z-1)] x^{z-2} \mathrm{e}^{-x}$$
on the interval $(0,\infty)$ is equal to zero (if $z>1$ of course).

The plot below shows this function for $z=3$ . The red area below and the blue area above the axis have (almost) the same size, so their contributions cancel.

[image]

Comment: I graphed this and you are right, but is $g(x)$ not equal to $e^-x$ ?

Comment: I graphed this and you are right, but is $g(x)$ not equal to $e^-x$ ? and $g'(x)$ is equal to $-e^-x$ ? That means that the part that equates to zero, after you have performed integration of parts is $-x^{(z-1)}e^-x$ summed from infinity to zero. The area between this curve and the x-axis is not zero, because the entire thing is below the x axis and it equals -2 in this case. Because of the decay curve of $e^{-x}$, it moves to the x-axis very rapidly, but it doesn't actually go over it into the first quadrant.

Comment: @SXW We have $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} \mathrm{e}^{-x} \, \mathrm{d} x$ and want to write this as $\int_0^\infty f(x) g'(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$ . To obtain the term you mentioned in the question we have to choose $f(x) = x^{z-1}$ and $g'(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x}$. But then integration yields $g(x) = - \mathrm{e}^{-x}$ if we set the arbitrary constant to zero.

Comment: Yes, $g(x)=-e^{-x}$ looks right to me. The expression goes from $\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}$ to two portions which are $-x^{z-1}e^{-x} \lim_{x \to \infty}$ and also $(z-1)\int_0^\infty x^{z-2} e^{-x}$

Comment: It's the first part that is confusing me. Doesn't $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ mean that you plug in infinity and then plug in zero, and subtract one from the other ? That gives 0-0 which certainly suggests that it equates to zero, unless you graph it and then you get a curve that describes an area under the x-axis that is -2 or -6  or -24, or some other factorial, with a negative sign in front.

Comment: @SXW The first part is indeed $\lim_{x \to \infty} (-x^{z-1} \mathrm{e}^{-x}) - (-0^{z-1} \mathrm{e}^{-0}) = 0$ . As I have tried to explain, this is not the area under the graph of $-x^{z-1} \mathrm{e}^{-x}$ but the one under its derivative, which is shown in my answer (for $z=3$) . This is true in general: $$ \int_a^b h'(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = h(b) - h(a) $$ is the area under the graph of $h'$, not the graph of $h$ !

Comment: Thanks, I got there in the end. In the lecture notes and books they always show this part, the part that equates to zero as $-x^{z-1} e^{-x}$ and then they follow it with a straight vertical line, with $\infty$ at its top and $0$ at the bottom. Is that the shorthand for "area under the derivative of this function" ?

Comment: @SXW Exactly! In general, one would write $$\int_a^b h'(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = h(x) \Bigg \rvert_a^b \equiv h(b) - h(a)$$ to denote the difference of the values of $h$ at $b$ and $a$ , which corresponds to the area between the graph of $h'$ and the $x$-axis .